# Add a Rich Text field inside a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rich-text

I have the following Rich Text field inside my site columns inside an online site collection:-

[image]

now when i add the above site column inside a document library >> the Rich Text facility will not be provided, and i will get a plain text field as follow:-

[image]

any advice on how i can add a Rich Text field inside a document library?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in SharePoint that **Rich text** or **Enhanced rich text** is disabled in document libraries by default, as well as the **Edit Multi-Text** option in Edit Form. See a UserVoice post [here](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/37876330-make-extended-rich-text-available-for-multiline).

Currently we can only use the FORMAT TEXT panel using classic experience. HTML elements are acceptable in modern experience though.

--

In addition, if you do not see that panel when editing document properties in classic experience, open the document library using SharePoint Designer and edit the column via *Lists and Libraries* > select library > *Edit list columns* under "Customization" > select (Enhanced) Rich Text column > *Column Settings* (, as is described in this [blog](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/rich-text-column-in-sharepoint-document-library.html)).

Uncheck “Enhanced Rich Text” and then check it again (the settings should all be selected by default). After that, **save the changes** in SharePoint Designer.

Now back to the Edit Form in the document library, you should be able to see the panel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for th workaround and info.. but it is recommended to do these changes?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev There is nothing to worry about. We don’t really change or add anything to the default settings, if you have noticed. We just help to activate the Rich Text feature by reconfigure it again using SharePoint Designer 2013. The checkboxes are checked by default when we create this Rich Text column, somehow it does not function in the first place.